# Touch Point on Screen GoogleMap SupportMapFragement

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, touch-event

I am working on GoogleMap Api v2.

I need to draw marker on to the screen where user will Tap.

And for that I am using

```
LatLng coordinates = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(
                     new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()));
```

But problem is i am not getting the place where onTouchEvent will come.

I tried adding overriding onTouchEvent in the Activity that contains SupportMapFragment.

I tried extending SupportMapFragment and in onCreateView setting the onTouchListener on the view like this.

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                GoogleMap map =  MyMapFragment.this.getMap();
                LatLng coordinates = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(
                       new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()));

           }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

But nothing seems to work.

Any Help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it after some doc search

```
GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener

Comment: Google Map api v2 made things really smooth for drawing interactive maps. Though many flexibilities are still pending. Like interactive views in the info window and many more